# How can I change a label's font and nothing else?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, fonts

When I set the font on a `UILabel` programmatically like below, sometimes it does exactly what I want, but with some fonts it also changes the font size. This is undesirable. Here is my code:

```
+(void)setFontFamily:(NSString*)fontFamily forView:(UIView*)view andSubViews:(BOOL)isSubViews {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] ||
        [view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] ||
        [view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)view;
        [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontFamily size:[[lbl font] pointSize]]];
    }

    if (isSubViews) {
        for (UIView *sview in view.subviews) {
            [self setFontFamily:fontFamily forView:sview andSubViews:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

I copied this from an `SO` answer a few months ago. It has always worked so far, but certain fonts seem to just not go under certain `font sizes`. For example I have a font called `KozGoPro-ExtraLight` and when I set it to a label with size 12 it remains that, but changes the font. I have the font `KozGoP6N-Light` (it came in the same package) and when I apply this one the `font size` of my label changes from 12 to 17 (any number under 17 changes to 17).

Why does this happen? Does it have something to do with the code I'm using or is it another one of Apple's quirks? Can I fix it, e.g. can I change the code so it doesn't f*ck up my font size while still being able to change the font?

- I'm testing on iOS7
- I'm using xcode 5.1.1

This is what I get if I log the following lines

```
NSLog(@"before:\n %@\n%f\n%f",[UIFont fontWithName:fontFamily size:[[lbl font] pointSize]],[[lbl font] pointSize],[lbl minimumScaleFactor]);
//set new font
NSLog(@"after:\n %@\n%f\n%f",[UIFont fontWithName:fontFamily size:[[lbl font] pointSize]],[[lbl font] pointSize],[lbl minimumScaleFactor]);
```

logs:

```
2014-09-19 12:37:06.287 rendezvouswebrtcbullshittestproject[876:60b] before:
 <UICTFont: 0x1559d4e0> font-family: "KozGoPro-ExtraLight"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt
15.000000
0.000000
2014-09-19 12:37:06.288 rendezvouswebrtcbullshittestproject[876:60b] after:
 <UICTFont: 0x1559d4e0> font-family: "KozGoPro-ExtraLight"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt
15.000000
0.000000
2014-09-19 12:37:06.296 rendezvouswebrtcbullshittestproject[876:60b] before:
 <UICTFont: 0x156a0930> font-family: "KozGoPr6N-Light"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt
15.000000
0.000000
2014-09-19 12:37:06.297 rendezvouswebrtcbullshittestproject[876:60b] after:
 <UICTFont: 0x156a0930> font-family: "KozGoPr6N-Light"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt
15.000000
0.000000
```

Comment: What do you have if you log: `[UIFont fontWithName:fontFamily size:[[lbl font] pointSize]]`,`[[lbl font] pointSize]` and [label minimumScaleFactor]?

Comment: @Larme I edited the log into the question.